# Update XSL file before transform

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

TNT supply manifest data as XML and an XSL file to transform that data into.

The output is then a HTML file of the manifest for printing.

This it the XSL file:

https://express.tnt.com/expresswebservices-website/stylesheets/HTMLManifestRenderer.xsl

In the xsl file there is the following:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="PACKAGE[position() >= 1 and position() < 4]" mode="int"/>
```

Which, using my extremely limited knowledge in this area, appears to stops more than 3 items being displayed in the Manifest.

I want to remove this limit. As simple as changing the "< 4" to "< 9999"

I have the following code that works:

```
public static string TransformXmlStringWithXslString(string xmlString, string XSLStylesheetUrl)
{
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Xml.AllowDefaultResolver", true);

    // process our xml
    XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlString));
    XPathDocument xPathDocument = new XPathDocument(xmlTextReader);

    XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(true, true);

    // process the xsl
    XmlTextReader xmlTextReaderXslt = new XmlTextReader(XSLStylesheetUrl);
    XslCompiledTransform xslCompiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslCompiledTransform.Load(xmlTextReaderXslt, settings, new XmlUrlResolver());

    // handle the output stream
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);

    // do the transform
    xslCompiledTransform.Transform(xPathDocument, null, textWriter);
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

What is the best way to update that value before pushing the XML into it?

Comment: Do not change!!! A schema is meant to make clients and server compatible.  If you change the schema you may not be able to transfer the data to another application.

Comment: @jdweng but in this case it's simply rendering a HTML of the manifest file for printing...

Comment: Is the data being supplied every larger than 3 items?  I do not think you will every get more than 3 items if the schema has 3 as max.

Comment: yes. sometimes there are more than 3 parcels being sent. we do not understand the "commercial" reason why they are imposing this limit. but for our use of the document we need more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than modifying the stylesheet, consider writing an overlay stylesheet that imports the supplied stylesheet and replaces the relevant template rule:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...>
<xsl:import href="existingStylesheet.xsl"/>
<xsl:param name="maxPackages" select="5"/>

<xsl:template match="CONSIGNMENT" mode="IntPacks">
<div class="row packages">
<div class="packagescolumn1">
<div class="Line100">
<font class="newheader"> Description (incl. packing and marks) </font>
</div>
</div>
<div class="packagescolumn2">
<div class="Line100">
<font class="newheader"> Dimensions (L x W x H) </font>
</div>
</div>
<div class="packagescolumn3">
<div class="Line100">
<font class="newheader"> Total Consignment Volume   </font>
<font class="newdata">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(TOTALVOLUME, '##0.000'), ' ', PACKAGE/VOLUME/@units)"/>
</font>
</div>
</div>
<xsl:apply-templates select="PACKAGE[position() >= 1 and position() &lt;= $maxPackages]" mode="int"/>
</div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have uploaded your file to https://sherprinsurance.blob.core.windows.net/xslhost/Manifest.xsl changing the href to the original file but it renders in my browser with an error. can you help?

Comment: @trevor, close the empty `xsl:import` with `/>`

Comment: @rene, which part of the solution needs explanation? Is it the general principle of xsl:import overriding declarations in an imported stylesheet?

Comment: @MichaelKay yes, that an import overrides an existing declaration was surprising to me. I always assumed it was hit or miss and/or implementation specific behavior, not specified behavior.

Comment: @rene: Absolutely not, import precedence is very carefully explained in the spec and is a very significant feature of the language, probably not widely enough understood. It's particularly important of course in the original use-case for XSLT, namely defining alternative renderings of the same XML, where one stylesheet can make small modifications to another.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to load the [XSL stylesheet](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/WhatIsXSL.html) (don't confuse it with an XML Schema!) into an XDocument and then find the element you want to change. This code find the specific element you're after and makes the change:

```
var xslNS = (XNamespace) "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform";
    
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"https://express.tnt.com/expresswebservices-website/stylesheets/HTMLManifestRenderer.xsl");
var xelement = xdoc
    .Descendants(xslNS + "apply-templates")
    .Where(e => (string) e.Attribute("select") == "PACKAGE[position() >= 1 and position() < 4]" 
       && (string) e.Attribute("mode") == "int");
var apply = xelement.First();
apply.SetAttributeValue("select", "PACKAGE[position() >= 1 and position() < 9999]");
```

You can then use the `CreateReader` method on the XDocument instance to get the reader that you need to get a Compiled XSL. Incorperating that in your code it would look like this:

```
public static string TransformXmlStringWithXslString(string xmlString, string XSLStylesheetUrl)
{
     AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Xml.AllowDefaultResolver", true);

     // process our xml
     XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlString));
     XPathDocument xPathDocument = new XPathDocument(xmlTextReader);

     XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(true, true);

     // process the xsl
     var xslNS = (XNamespace) "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform";
     
     var xdoc = XDocument.Load(XSLStylesheetUrl);
     var xelement = xdoc
         .Descendants(xslNS +"apply-templates")
         .Where(e => (string) e.Attribute("select") == "PACKAGE[position() >= 1 and position() < 4]" 
            && (string) e.Attribute("mode") == "int");
     var apply = xelement.First();
     apply.SetAttributeValue("select", "PACKAGE[position() >= 1 and position() < 9999]");
     
     XslCompiledTransform xslCompiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
     xslCompiledTransform.Load(xdoc.CreateReader(), settings, new XmlUrlResolver());

     // handle the output stream
     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);

     // do the transform
     xslCompiledTransform.Transform(xPathDocument, null, textWriter);
     return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```